# How to set the fields parameter in a Google Drive Go API call?

Tags: go, google-drive-api

As explained on

https://developers.google.com/drive/web/performance#partial-response

Once can set the "fields" parameter of an HTTP request to obtain a partial response containing only the fields explicitly requested. There are many examples on how to do this in languages like Python, but I could not find anything using the Go API. The FilesListCall type has no method that allows to do this, and I also cannot find any other way to tweak the HTTP request send by the Go API.

Is there a way to do this at all, or am we condamned to transfer large amounts of unneeded data?

Comment: There seems to be an open issue related to this at https://code.google.com/p/google-api-go-client/issues/detail?id=5 "support global fields" but it seems to have been open since 2011.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware that the issue had been reported. Well, since Google is on it, I guess we can expect it to be closed sometime around 2025. :/

Comment: I have to take my last comment back - a Google engineer just implemented support for partial responses in the Go API 2 days after I posted a comment on the report! Thanks again for poiting it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Intermernet explained, the feature was just not implemented when I asked the question. However, after posting a comment on the opened feature request, a Google engineer immediatly implemented it:

http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/google-api-go-client/googleapi#Field

Thanks to Google for the quick reaction on this much needed feature!